# What are some javascript charting libraries that allow plotting stock prices?

Tags: javascript, charts, stocks, forex

I need to be able to represent high and lows using a javascript charting libraries. All the libraries I have seen only allow defining the "high" value and the low value is always defaulted to zero.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/

You can draw all kinds of fancy charts using this. Some are static image charts, others are dynamic, interactive charts.

Answer (score 2):

You can find some options by going to:

- http://www.amcharts.com/stock/
- http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock
- http://www.dygraphs.com/